# ASP.NET I can't write into HTML Input

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a simple login page, which I wanted to beautify with some snow in the background. However this makes it unable for me to input anything into the input box, even if z-index is set to 100:

```css
/* CSS (Login) : */

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,
.form button:active,
.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}

.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}

body {
  background: #76b852;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

/* CSS (Snow) : */

.background {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.winter-is-coming,
.snow {
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.winter-is-coming {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: initial;
  background: #333;
}

.snow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: falling linear infinite both;
  transform: translate3D(0, -100%, 0);
}

.snow--near {
  animation-duration: 10s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    large-075d267ecbc42e3564c8ed43516dd557.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--near+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.snow--mid {
  animation-duration: 20s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    medium-0b8a5e0732315b68e1f54185be7a1ad9.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--mid+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.snow--far {
  animation-duration: 30s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    small-1ecd03b1fce08c24e064ff8c0a72c519.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--far+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes falling {
  0% {
    transform: translate3D(-7.5%, -100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3D(7.5%, 100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="winter-is-coming login-page">
  <div class="snow snow--near"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--near snow--alt"></div>

  <div class="snow snow--mid"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--mid snow--alt"></div>

  <div class="snow snow--far"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--far snow--alt"></div>
  <div class="form" style="z-index:100;">
    <form class="login-form">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="usernameBox" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passwordBox" />
      <button runat="server" onclick="loginClicked">login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that the error lays in Snow.css, because if I don't use it, I can use my login normally, but I can't find anything wrong within the file

Comment: why you tag as c#?

Comment: I thought cause ASP uses C# and forgot that it has nothing to do with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointer-events` is to be set on `.snow` only ;)

```css
/* CSS (Login) : */

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,
.form button:active,
.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}

.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}

body {
  background: #76b852;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


/* CSS (Snow) : */

.background {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.winter-is-coming,
.snow {
  z-index: -1;
}

.winter-is-coming {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: initial;
  background: #333;
}

.snow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: falling linear infinite both;
  transform: translate3D(0, -100%, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.snow--near {
  animation-duration: 10s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    large-075d267ecbc42e3564c8ed43516dd557.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--near+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.snow--mid {
  animation-duration: 20s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    medium-0b8a5e0732315b68e1f54185be7a1ad9.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--mid+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.snow--far {
  animation-duration: 30s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    small-1ecd03b1fce08c24e064ff8c0a72c519.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--far+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes falling {
  0% {
    transform: translate3D(-7.5%, -100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3D(7.5%, 100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="winter-is-coming login-page">
  <div class="snow snow--near"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--near snow--alt"></div>

  <div class="snow snow--mid"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--mid snow--alt"></div>

  <div class="snow snow--far"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--far snow--alt"></div>
  <div class="form" style="z-index:100;">
    <form class="login-form">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="usernameBox" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passwordBox" />
      <button runat="server" onclick="loginClicked">login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

or reset on the form.

```css
/* CSS (Login) : */

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  pointer-events:auto
}

.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,
.form button:active,
.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}

.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}

body {
  background: #76b852;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, /*#8DC26F*/
  #333);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


/* CSS (Snow) : */

.background {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.winter-is-coming,
.snow {
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.winter-is-coming {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: initial;
  background: #333;
}

.snow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: falling linear infinite both;
  transform: translate3D(0, -100%, 0);
}

.snow--near {
  animation-duration: 10s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    large-075d267ecbc42e3564c8ed43516dd557.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--near+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.snow--mid {
  animation-duration: 20s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    medium-0b8a5e0732315b68e1f54185be7a1ad9.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--mid+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.snow--far {
  animation-duration: 30s;
  background-image: url('https://dl6rt3mwcjzxg.cloudfront.net/assets/snow/snow-    small-1ecd03b1fce08c24e064ff8c0a72c519.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.snow--far+.snow--alt {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes falling {
  0% {
    transform: translate3D(-7.5%, -100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3D(7.5%, 100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="winter-is-coming login-page">
  <div class="snow snow--near"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--near snow--alt"></div>

  <div class="snow snow--mid"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--mid snow--alt"></div>

  <div class="snow snow--far"></div>
  <div class="snow snow--far snow--alt"></div>
  <div class="form" style="z-index:100;">
    <form class="login-form">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="usernameBox" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passwordBox" />
      <button runat="server" onclick="loginClicked">login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```